# What is the 'mit A-Y' in 'ist dort die Firma Mayer mit A-Y'?

Tags: phrase, person-names

I see this conversation in Studio 21:

> A: »Heier«
>   B: »Guten Morgen, ist dort die Firma Mayer **mit A-Y**?«
>   A: »Nein, hier ist Heier. HEIER.«
>   B: »Oh, Entschuldigung ...«

What is the ‘mit A-Y’?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In ancient times, a *Meier* was a land agent (the administrator of an estate). The estate that he administrated was called *Meierei*.

Today many people have the name of this old profession as their family name. But there are dozens of different spellings with exactly the same pronunciation [ˈmaɪ̯ɐ].

Some of the most common spellings are:

- Meier (mit E, I)
- Maier (mit A, I)
- Meyer (mit E, Y)
- Mayer (mit A, Y)
- Mair (mit A, I, ohne E zwischen I und R)
- Mayr (mit A, Y, ohne E zwischen Y und R)

You often say some similiar explanations to clarify the spelling for family names with a spelling, that is not so clear when you just hear it. For example, I often say:
*»Schölnast (nur ein L, das L vor dem N)«*.

Comment: Gut zu wissen! Danke!

Comment: *Schölnast, nur ein „l“ vor dem „n“* [oder Pfeiffer, mit 3 „f“.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=h19YjALZQ_g)

Comment: *Geiselmann wie Geisterbahn, nur mit -elmann statt -terbahn.* (Yes, a joke, but it anway clarifies the three letters that can cause trouble.)

Comment: @Narusan: Ein Freund von mir heißt tatsächlich Pfeiffer, und er verwendet auch tatsächlich die Floskel »Pfeiffer mit 3 F«, was bei jedem anfangs für Verwirrung, dann aber für einen anhaltenden Lerneffekt sorgt. Ich habe aber auch einen Onkel, eine Tante und einen Cousin, die Pfeifer heißen. »Pfeifer mit 2 F« ist in diesem Fall bei weitem nicht so zielführend (führt bei vielen zur Schreibung mit Doppel-F) wie das eigentlich falsche »Pfeifer mit nur einem F«.

Comment: Interessant! ich kannte *Meierei* nur im Sinne von *Molkerei* oder *Sennerei*, doch so scheint *Meierei* nur in Norddeutschland gebraucht zu werden.

Comment: @Philipp: Den Begriff Meierei kennt man in Österreich erst seit relativ kurzer Zeit (wieder?), damit verbindet man allerdings Cafés und Restaurants: z.B.: http://www.meierei.at oder https://www.steirereck.at/meierei/ Noch vor 20 Jahren kannte kaum jemand in Ö dieses Wort. Der Nachname Meier (in allen Schreibweisen) ist in Österreich auch deutlich seltener als in Deutschland (Platz 14 in Ö, aber Platz 2 in D), und kommt in Ö in Städten signifikant häufiger vor als am Land, was ein Indiz dafür ist, dass die Meiers nicht *schon immer* in Österreich waren, sondern eingewandert sind.

Answer (score 10):

It's simply spelling out a and y for clarification.

That's done often with last names like *Mayer*, because there are many other common spellings of that name like e.g. *Meier* or *Maier*.

Comment: Then `die Firma Meier mit E-I`?

Comment: @lerner Exactly.

Comment: More exactly: Die Firma Meier mit E-I-E.